# How To Append Ajax Response (Array Of Objects) To Tbody of A Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please help me to figure it out how to append reciving data from Ajax into a tbody of an existing table?

In my HTML I have a Table Like:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Projects </th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Road Length (Km)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Powerline Length (Km)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Penstock (Km)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Installed Capacity (MW)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Annual Firm Energy (GW/h)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Cost of Energy ($/MWh)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Footprint (Km)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Cost Per Year ($)</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>    </tbody>
</table>
```

and js file is like

```
request.done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

which the output in console looks like

[image]

these are the values to be place in the `>tr><td></td></tr>`

```
AnnualFirmEnergy: "91.2335550"
CostOfEnergy: "183.835765"
CostPerYear: "16771990.38"
Footprint: "182.3077770"
InstalledCapacity: "31.320802"
Penstock: "5000.000000"
PowerLineLength: "37.384781"
ProjectID: "12910"
RoadLength: "29.350976"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$.each()`

```
request.done(function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      var tr = $("<tr />")
     $.each(value, function(k, v) {
       tr.append(
         $("<td />", {
           html: v
          })[0].outerHTML
       );
      $("table tbody").append(tr)
     })
   })
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/11p7e3z6/

Comment: Thanks guest271314 but this is just adding all data in one column!

Comment: @Behseini Actually considered that at some point yesterday. Try creating `tr` variable in first `.$.each()` , append `td` elements to `tr` variable at second `$.each()` . If create example data object with `html` at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net will correct

Comment: Thanks guest271314 this is working but I am getting all data , is there any way to skip from Latitude and Longitude since I do not want to display them here?

Answer (score 1):

Let me show two basic principles of access to elements of json array.
Those principles are shown in code below - please read my comments.
I suppose it will be useful for our community.

```js
var data = {1:{AnnualFirmEnergy: "91.2335550",
CostOfEnergy: "183.835765",
CostPerYear: "16771990.38",
Footprint: "182.3077770",
InstalledCapacity: "31.320802",
Penstock: "5000.000000",
PowerLineLength: "37.384781",
ProjectID: "12910",
RoadLength: "29.350976"},2:{AnnualFirmEnergy: "91.2335550",
CostOfEnergy: "183.835765",
CostPerYear: "16771990.38",
Footprint: "182.3077770",
InstalledCapacity: "31.320802",
Penstock: "5000.000000",
PowerLineLength: "37.384781",
ProjectID: "12910",
RoadLength: "29.350976"},3:{AnnualFirmEnergy: "91.2335550",
CostOfEnergy: "183.835765",
CostPerYear: "16771990.38",
Footprint: "182.3077770",
InstalledCapacity: "31.320802",
Penstock: "5000.000000",
PowerLineLength: "37.384781",
ProjectID: "12910",
RoadLength: "29.350976"}}

for(var i in data) //i = 1, 2, 3 ...
   {
     var rn = $('<tr class=""></tr>');
       //first approach to add data (not flexible)
  rn.append('<td>'+data[i].ProjectID+'</td>');
        rn.append('<td>'+data[i].RoadLength+'</td>');
        rn.append('<td>'+data[i].PowerLineLength+'</td>');

    // here add all columns
    $('#example').append(rn);

       //second - right - approach to add data.  
    //in this casу data in your JSON array
       //have had order like your table head arrangement
       var rd = $('<tr class=""></tr>');
       var o=data[i];

       for(var j in o)//j='AnnualFirmEnergy', ...
       {
           rd.append('<td>'+o[j]+'</td>');
           $('#example').append(rd);
       }
   }
```

```css
TABLE {
    width: 300px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    border-bottom: none; 
   }
   TD, TH {
    padding: 3px; 
   }
   TH {
    text-align: left; 
    background: black; 
    color: white; 
    border: 1px solid white; 
   }
   TD {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Projects </th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Road Length (Km)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Powerline Length (Km)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Penstock (Km)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Installed Capacity (MW)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Annual Firm Energy (GW/h)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Cost of Energy ($/MWh)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Footprint (Km)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Cost Per Year ($)</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use some kind of templating engine for cloning the data into the DOM, you'll very soon descend into a labyrinth of messy unmaintainable code.

Below is an example using the dna.js engine, a library I contribute to, but the approach is pretty common.  The basic idea is to define data fields in the HTML and then pass the JSON data to the engine for cloning.

**HTML**

```
<table id=example>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Projects</th>
         <th>Road Length (Km)</th>
         <th>Powerline Length (Km)</th>
         <th>Penstock (Km)</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr id=energy>
         <td>~~AnnualFirmEnergy~~</td>
         <td>~~CostOfEnergy~~</td>
         <td>~~CostPerYear~~</td>
         <td>~~Footprint~~</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
...
<script src=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/3.2/jquery.min.js></script>
<script src=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/dna.js/1.2/dna.min.js></script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function handle(data) { dna.clone('energy', data); }
request.done(handle);
```

Yep, it's that simple.  Note that there is no HTML in the JS, so the JS is easier to maintain and the HTML is easier to style.

Fiddle with the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/tw37poyw/2

[image: AJAX table]

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {1:{AnnualFirmEnergy: "91.2335550",
CostOfEnergy: "183.835765",
CostPerYear: "16771990.38",
Footprint: "182.3077770",
InstalledCapacity: "31.320802",
Penstock: "5000.000000",
PowerLineLength: "37.384781",
ProjectID: "12910",
RoadLength: "29.350976"},2:{AnnualFirmEnergy: "91.2335550",
CostOfEnergy: "183.835765",
CostPerYear: "16771990.38",
Footprint: "182.3077770",
InstalledCapacity: "31.320802",
Penstock: "5000.000000",
PowerLineLength: "37.384781",
ProjectID: "12910",
RoadLength: "29.350976"},3:{AnnualFirmEnergy: "91.2335550",
CostOfEnergy: "183.835765",
CostPerYear: "16771990.38",
Footprint: "182.3077770",
InstalledCapacity: "31.320802",
Penstock: "5000.000000",
PowerLineLength: "37.384781",
ProjectID: "12910",
RoadLength: "29.350976"}}

for(var i in data) //i = 1, 2, 3 ...
   {
        var rn = $('<tr class=""></tr>');
       //first approach to add data (not flexible)
        rn.append('<td>'+data[i].ProjectID+'</td>');
        rn.append('<td>'+data[i].RoadLength+'</td>');
        rn.append('<td>'+data[i].PowerLineLength+'</td>');

    // here add all columns
    $('#example').append(rn);

       //second - right - approach to add data.  
       //in this casу data in your JSON array
       //have had order like your table head arrangement
       var rd = $('<tr class=""></tr>');
       var o=data[i];

       for(var j in o)//j='AnnualFirmEnergy', ...
       {
           rd.append('<td>'+o[j]+'</td>');
           $('#example').append(rd);
       }
   }
```

```css
TABLE {
    width: 300px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    border-bottom: none; 
   }
   TD, TH {
    padding: 3px; 
   }
   TH {
    text-align: left; 
    background: black; 
    color: white; 
    border: 1px solid white; 
   }
   TD {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Projects </th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Road Length (Km)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Powerline Length (Km)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Penstock (Km)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Installed Capacity (MW)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Annual Firm Energy (GW/h)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Cost of Energy ($/MWh)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Footprint (Km)</th>
    <th valign="middle" class="c-font">Cost Per Year ($)</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Comment: Thanks for your response. Next time i will make better content with explaination